# why self.method_name cannot access private method ? where as only private method_name can in any method can access private method in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class Person
  def one
    @var = 99
    self.two
  end
  private
  def two
    p @var
  end
end
p=Person.new
p.one
```

when i run this code code i get error as
main.rb:4:in `one': private method` two' called for #<Person:0x00000000965a28 @var=99> (NoMethodError)
from main.rb:12:in `'

```
class Person
  def one
    @var = 99
    two
  end
  private
  def two
    p @var
  end
end
p=Person.new
p.one
```

when i run this i get output as 99.
so when the p.one calls it goes to method one execute it when it find method two without any receiver object (which means method two have self as object ) and it successfully executes the method.

But When i manually give self.two it gives me error why ?

what is difference between method call of two VS self.two ?

Comment: [This article](https://dev.to/adamlombard/ruby-class-methods-vs-instance-methods-4aje) should help you understand the difference between **class methods** vs. **instance methods** in Ruby.

Comment: This isn't a class vs instance thing, @KarimTarek .. the issue is that private methods cannot be called with an explicit receiver, even if it's `self` ...

Comment: yes Exactly, it was asked by interview to me i was bit consfused that time. actually self means (current object 'p' ). and self.two means (p.two) but here two is private method we cannot access private method of class using explicit receive.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why self.method_name cannot access private method ?

Because that is how `private` is defined, at least in the older version of Ruby that you are using.

It *can* in current versions of Ruby. The behavior you are describing only exists in older versions of Ruby.

If I run your code using my Ruby installation (Ruby 3.0.0 as implemented by YARV 3.0.0), I don't get an error.

Here is how `private` has *historically* been defined:

> A `private` method can only be called without a receiver.

See, for example section 13.3.5.3 *Private methods* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html):

> A private method cannot be invoked with an explicit receiver, i.e., a private method cannot be invoked if a *primary-expression* or a *chained-method-invocation* occurs at the position which corresponds to the method receiver in the method invocation

Note that this is not the whole story, however.

How do you call a private attribute writer under this rule? The answer is: you can't! You can't use `self.foo = bar` because you are not allowed to use an explicit receiver and you can't use `foo = bar` because that is an assignment to the local variable `foo` and not a call to the attribute writer `foo=`.

So, there is actually an exception to this rule:

> A `private` method can only be called without a receiver, unless it is an attribute writer, then it can also be called with a receiver that is the literal pseudo-variable `self`.

Note that it *has* to be the literal pseudo-variable `self`. It cannot be *any* arbitrary expression that evaluates to the same object.

I.e. this is allowed:

```ruby
self.foo = bar
```

but this is not:

```ruby
this = self
this.foo = bar
# private method `foo=' called for #<…> (NoMethodError)
```

The exact text from the ISO Ruby Language Specification is:

> A private method cannot be invoked with an explicit receiver, i.e., a private method cannot be invoked if a *primary-expression* or a *chained-method-invocation* occurs at the position which corresponds to the method receiver in the method invocation, except for a method invocation of any of the following forms where the *primary-expression* is a *self-expression*.
>
> - *single-method-assignment*
> - *abbreviated-method-assignment*
> - *single-indexing-assignment*
> - *abbreviated-indexing-assignment*

However, this still doesn't solve all problems: what about operators, for example `self + bar` or `!self`? What about methods whose names are reserved words like `class`?

The proposed rules became more and more complicated. For some insight, see the following discussion on the Ruby issue tracker:
[Bug #9907 *Abbreviated method assignment with private `attr_writer`/`attr_reader` does not work.*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907) [Disclaimer: I am the one who filed the bug.]

To make this work, you would have to change the rule to something like

> A `private` method can only be called without a receiver, unless it is an attribute writer or an operator, then it can also be called with a receiver that is the literal pseudo-variable `self`, including in an abbreviated method assignment.

As you can see, the rule gets rather complex.

A much simpler rule was proposed, and is now implemented as of Ruby 2.7:

- [Feature #11297 *Allow private method of `self` to be called*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11297)
- [Feature #16123 *Allow calling a private method with `self.`*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16123)

The rule now is:

> A `private` method can only be called without a receiver or with an explicit receiver that is the literal pseudo-variable `self`.

You might ask yourself, why not use this *even simpler* rule?

> A `private` method can only be called with the receiver `self`.

The reason is that both the old rule, the in-between rules, and the new rule [can be decided statically, in fact even syntactically at parse time](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907#note-9), whereas this very simple rule cannot.